# Conditional mean of x given y>0 for normal distributions

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation

I need to find the conditional expectation of $X$ given $Z>0$ where
 - both $X$ and $Z$ are normally distributed and I know their distributions. In particular they both have mean zero;
 - $Z$ is a function of $X$, in particular it is something like $Z=aX+bY$ where $Y$ is another random variable of which I know the distribution.
I'm stuck because in books I only find $E(X|Z=z)$, but not my problem, which I am not even sure I wrote properly so it would be important to understand whether and how one can find that expectation. Thank you all

Comment: I suspect that simulation may be faster though perhaps less insightful.  For example if $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. normal with mean $0$ (so $Z$ is also normal with mean $0$, though with variance multiplied by $a^2+b^2$) and if $a$ is non-negative then $E[X\mid Z\gt 0]$ is between $0$ and $\sqrt{\frac2{\pi}} \approx 0.798$: if $\frac ab = \frac12$ then simulation suggests it is about $0.357$; if $\frac ab =1$ then about $0.564$; if $\frac ab =2$ then about $0.714$

Answer (score 0):

- Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independently and identically normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $1$.  Then $(X,Y)$ would have a bivariate distribution which has circular symmetry about $(0,0)$
- $Z = aX+bY$ would also be normally distributed with mean $0$ but variance $a^2+b^2$.  The condition $Z \gt 0$ would correspond to points one side of a line $ax+by =0$
- In the special case where $a=1$ and $b=0$, i.e. $Z=X$, the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Z \gt 0$ would be a [half-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution) with mean $\mathbb E[X\mid Z\gt 0] = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$, while we would still have $\mathbb E[Y\mid Z\gt 0]=0$
- but in the more general case the point $(\mathbb E[X\mid Z\gt 0],\mathbb E[Y\mid Z\gt 0])$ would lie on the line $y=\frac ba x$ at a distance $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$ from $(0,0)$, i.e. at the point $\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}},\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)$ so $$\mathbb E[X\mid Z\gt 0]=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

This picture may help

[image]

To take particular examples confirming my earlier simulations

- with $a=1$, $b=2$ you get $\mathbb E[X\mid Z\gt 0] = \sqrt{\frac{2}{5\pi}} \approx 0.35682$
- with $a=1$, $b=1$ you get $\mathbb E[X\mid Z\gt 0] = \sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi}} \approx 0.56419$
- with $a=2$, $b=1$ you get $\mathbb E[X\mid Z\gt 0] = \sqrt{\frac{8}{5\pi}} \approx 0.71365$

Comment: Thank you. Just to be sure, does this mean I cannot write this expectation as an integral, following a general definition?

Comment: You can write it as an integral, perhaps something like:  $\dfrac{\int_{x=-\infty}^\infty \int_{y=-\frac{a}{b}x}^\infty  x \phi(x)\phi(y)\,dy\, dx} {\int_{x=-\infty}^\infty \int_{y=-\frac{a}{b}x}^\infty  \phi(x)\phi(y)\,dy\, dx}$ which I think you may be able to simplify slightly to $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty   2x \,\phi(x)\,\Phi\left(\frac{a}{b}x\right)\, dx $.  Good luck turning that into $\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi}}\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$

Comment: Again thank you. Is there a reference where I can find more on the subject? I am not really interested in computing the final value of the integral, but the second expression you wrote is close to what I need to obtain, except for the argument of the cdf... perhaps this is due to my simplification of the problem in the question. Maybe a problem is that $Y$ in my case is not standard normal

Comment: As I said in another comment, the quickest way to a good approximation is likely to be simulation, and that should be able to cope with $Y$ having another distribution